# Solving ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis when exploding multiple columns with different lenghts

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to solve this common issue, which is due when trying to explode multiple columns and the lists inside the respective column have not the same length:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Student':['J.M.', 'M.G.', 'L.D.'], 'Subject':[['mathematics', 'history', 'literature'], ['physics', 'mathematics', 'geography', 'history'], ['latin', 'literature', 'mathematics']], 'Score':[[10, 8, 8.5], [5, 4, 8, 8.5], [4,5, 5]],'Score2':[[10], [5, 4, 8,8.5], [4,5, 5]]})
df = df.apply(pd.Series.explode)
```

In this example, the first `Score` list has 3 elements the first `Score2` list only1. I am trying to solve this issue applying a function to check the length of the to list and to append to the shorter list an empty string. Is there a better way?

Comment: When the score has 1 element can we assume it will map to the first item in the other columns?

Comment: @anky Yes exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming when the list has just 1 element, it maps to the first element of the other lists in other columns, We can try with `zip_longest`:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

cols = ['Subject', 'Score', 'Score2']
def fun(x):
    return list(zip_longest(*x))

s = pd.Series(map(fun,df[cols].to_records(index=False))).explode()

out = df.drop(cols,1).join(pd.DataFrame(s.tolist(),columns=cols,index=s.index))
```

---

```
print(out)

  Student      Subject  Score  Score2
0    J.M.  mathematics   10.0    10.0
0    J.M.      history    8.0     NaN
0    J.M.   literature    8.5     NaN
1    M.G.      physics    5.0     5.0
1    M.G.  mathematics    4.0     4.0
1    M.G.    geography    8.0     8.0
1    M.G.      history    8.5     8.5
2    L.D.        latin    4.0     4.0
2    L.D.   literature    5.0     5.0
2    L.D.  mathematics    5.0     5.0
```

Comment: @GM Thats okay for me :) Subject is in the column list since it had to be exploded as well. since each Student has Multiple subjects as a list in a row

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, you can run a for loop of explosions:

```
for col in df:
    df = df.explode(col)
```

I get

```
>>> df

   Student      Subject Score Score2
0     J.M.  mathematics    10     10
0     J.M.  mathematics     8     10
0     J.M.  mathematics   8.5     10
0     J.M.      history    10     10
0     J.M.      history     8     10
..     ...          ...   ...    ...
2     L.D.  mathematics     5      5
2     L.D.  mathematics     5      5
2     L.D.  mathematics     5      4
2     L.D.  mathematics     5      5
2     L.D.  mathematics     5      5

[100 rows x 4 columns]
```